# Viewing the full Skype chat history

Tags: macos, skype, logging, history

I have Skype 2.8 on Mac OS X 10.5.8.

Under the the chat menu is an option called "Recent Chats".  This allows me to see logs of recent chats, but not of older ones.

I know the older ones are stored because they are in `~/Library/Application Support/Skype/username/chatmsg256.dbb`.  This file when put in a text editor has text chat information from all my previous Skype chats.  It is however stored in an unknown file format that I do not know how to parse.

Does Skype have a built-in log viewer (like Adium's) that I can use to access these older logs?

Comment: they used to have the very nice feature to export chat history to HTML. unfortunately, this feature is history since version 4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if this shows the *entire* history, but try the following. Whether the contact is online or offline, pop up the chat window.

[image: Click blue chat button]

Then click "All" under "View earlier messages:".

[image: Click all]

Alternatively, click the gear icon for the contact and select "View Chat History". That generates an html file that is opened in your web browser window.

The reason I'm not sure if this shows all the history is because I can't fully remember when my chat history began on this computer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  This seems like the way you're supposed to do this in Skype.  The weird thing is that this will not work to find chats with people who are not on your list anymore.  I'm not sure how that is supposed to be done.  This also suggests that there is no way to do a keyword search.  This type of message history interface is seriously weak compared to Adium's Chat Transcript Viewer.

Comment: I definitely agree. I really like Adium's chat history viewer as well. For Windows, I found an app called skypr (http://www.osiwanlan.de/skypr/) that I've never used, but it would still depend on there being chat history to display, which may not be the case for deleted contacts.

Comment: The chat logs with deleted contacts are in the log file.  I just don't know how to get to them (or if you can even get to them) from Skype's interface.

Answer (score 59):

Skype stores its chat history in a SQLite database: `~/Library/Application Support/Skype/YourSkypeName/main.db`. You can use the command line `sqlite3` tool to view the chat logs.

### Find out user names of your chat partners

The following command in Terminal (I'm assuming you're using the `bash` shell) lists all your chat partners' user names:

> `sqlite3 /Users/danielbeck/Library/Application\ Support/Skype/YourSkypeName/main.db 'SELECT DISTINCT(dialog_partner) FROM Messages;'`

### Extract all messages to and from a specific chat partner

#### Option A. Write to terminal

To print all messages to and from a certain chat partner (`theOtherPersonsUserName`), use the following command:

> `sqlite3 /Users/danielbeck/Library/Application\ Support/Skype/YourSkypeName/main.db "SELECT author, from_dispname, datetime(timestamp, 'unixepoch') as date, body_xml FROM Messages where dialog_partner = 'theOtherPersonsUserName' ORDER BY timestamp;"`

This will print one message per line, chronologically, with sending username, display name, date, and text, like the following:

> danielbecks-username|Daniel Beck|2012-02-03 08:47:53|Just testing something

#### Option B. Write to file

You can write this chat log directly to a file. Run the following to write the log with `theOtherPersonsUserName` to the file `theOtherPersonsUserName.log`:

> `sqlite3 /Users/danielbeck/Library/Application\ Support/Skype/YourSkypeName/main.db "SELECT author, from_dispname, datetime(timestamp, 'unixepoch') as date, body_xml FROM Messages where dialog_partner = 'theOtherPersonsUserName' ORDER BY timestamp;" > "theOtherPersonsUserName.log"`

---

Of course, you can also open `main.db` in any SQLite database viewer and go from there.

Comment: For other users with the same problem, if you have a lot of "chat partners", terminal may take some time to present you the list. In my case it was about two minutes. It seems like nothing is happening, so you may be tempted to close terminal, but you just have to **wait**. Then type the following command (SELECT author etc.), with the right user ID, and the conversation history will show up. Once your chat conversation appears in terminal, you can copy it into a word processor file and then polish it a little, if you want to.

Comment: `main.db` has gone away: `find -name main.db` finds nothing. The content is in files like `chatmsg256.dbb`, but opening these results in "Error: file is encrypted or is not a database". Any idea what works these days?

Comment: @JeanJordaan What version of Skype? What operating system? I also have these files, but they're from 2010...

Comment: @DanielBeck sorry for the incomplete information. Ubuntu Linux, Skype 2.2.0.35
This is from 2011, and I see there is a 4.2.0.11 available. I wonder if upgrading would migrate my old chats ...

Comment: The old `chatmsg256.dbb` format is described at http://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/index.php?/archives/231-Skype-Logs.html

Comment: With the Skype add-on as mentioned by @Andre Borges I can check the database, but I wonder how you can select all conversation made in a particular group. Ideas?

Comment: Never mind - chatname is the one for finding all chats in a group. Just need to check the table for the group id generated

Answer (score 2):

Just want to provide some more easy-to-use and up-to-date ways to view Skype logs:

- Skyperious (https://suurjaak.github.io/Skyperious/) - cross-platform GUI tool for manipulating Skype logs
- SkypeBrowser (http://www.skypebrowser.com/) - a web tool with similar functionality
- Any SQLite manager (like [this Firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/)) - gives you full access to all the data stored by Skype, including messages (usage details are provided in Daniel Beck's answer)

Answer (score 1):

Try [SkypeHistoryViewer](http://skypehistory.sourceforge.net).

> A small program that will allow the
>   user to open all history of Skype
>   activity that is on a PC, check your
>   kids usage, who there talking to what
>   there saying or check on a cheating
>   partner. Currently for Windows Vista
>   and 7.

Answer (score 0):

From Skype 8 on Mac,the path of the database file is changed. it is below:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Skype for Desktop/databases
```

reference : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/all/skype-on-mac-blank-screen-at-startup/4e63b629-cbb4-41d6-94e2-94c17bba097e