# Are there any third party Skype chat log viewers for the mac?

Tags: macos, skype, history, chat

According to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/93682/viewing-skype-chat-history) question, Skype's chat history viewer is limited - it won't show chats for users no longer in your contact list, cannot allow for search, and generally is not as useful when you're, for example, looking at multiple chat histories coming from multiple machines.

There appears to be a tool for viewing the chat history on windows (Skypr) - is there an equivalent one for the mac?

Comment: You might want to add OSX to your tags.

Comment: doesn't appear so to me, but it should be trivial to write one in ruby...i'm looking into it.  email me aking1012 _a__t___ amcomworks,com and i'll let you know if i finish it.  it would also make an interesting encase plug-in

Answer (score 0):

What about `gmail` or almost any other email client, web or desktop based? You can automatically save all your chat history there using Skype add-on [G-Recorder](http://www.g-recorder.com). I'm a co-author of this app so I won't list other benefits.