# Skype: Decode time stamps

Tags: macos, skype, sed, sqlite

I'm trying to extract the chat history between myself and my SO on Skype for OSX. I've managed to pull out the information and strip out the unnecessary XML formatting with the following command:

`sqlite3 /path/to/main.db "SELECT author,timestamp, body_xml FROM messages WHERE dialog_partner = 'so_username'" | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' - > output.txt`

This seems fine, but what I notice is that the timestamps in the output file are in some bizarre non-human readable format. Is there a way I can parse these?

Comment: Why don't you post some timestamp samples here so people can take a look, instead of requiring them to duplicate your work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. Here's the query:

`SELECT author, from_dispname, datetime(timestamp, 'unixepoch') as date, body_xml FROM Messages where dialog_partner = 'sousername' ORDER BY timestamp;`

As per [Viewing the full Skype chat history](https://superuser.com/questions/93682/viewing-skype-chat-history).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. It works in Database browser under XP:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT `rowid`,* FROM `SMSes`  ORDER BY `rowid` ASC);
SELECT `rowid`,datetime(timestamp, 'unixepoch') as date, * FROM `SMSes`  ORDER BY `date` ASC LIMIT 0, 50000;